# IORedis connection refused

Tags: node.js, docker, express, redis, backend

at the moment I'm trying to develop a small backend as proof of concept for myself. I'm using docker to connect the database redis and the express server. Everything is working fine except that I'm unable to connect to my redis-server if I'm using a password for authentication.

Have a look at my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
volumes:
  portfolio-data:
  portfolio-cache:
services:
  database:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGODB_ROOT_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - portfolio-data:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./config/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - portfolio-cache:/data
    command: ["redis-server", "/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
  portfolio-api:
    image: portfolio-api
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - API_PORT=8000
      - DB_HOST=$MONGO_HOST
      - DB_PORT=27017
      - DB_USER=$MONGO_USER
      - DB_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
      - REDIS_HOST=$REDIS_HOST
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=$REDIS_PASSWORD
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - REDIS_SECRET=$REDIS_SECRET
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

The redis service is the redis server of course. I've used the standard redis.conf where I've changed the requirepass password to my choosen password. Here I connect to my redis server:

```js
const redis = new Redis({
  host: redisConfig.host,
  port: redisConfig.port,
  password: redisConfig.password
});


redis.on('error', (err: Error) => {
  backendLogger.error(err.message);
});

redis.on('connect', () => {
  backendLogger.info('Connected successfully to redis');
});
```

The output for this code snippet is:

```bash
2022-09-28T06:46:29.707Z error:  connect ECONNREFUSED <ip>
```

I can connect to my redis server from the redis client with the password. Without the configuration file the connection via IORedis is working like expected e.g. I receive the output:

```bash
Connected successfully to redis
```

Does anyone have a idea why the connection is refused if i pass my configuration file and authenticate via password?

Comment: Did you try to connect via url ? EG ```redis://:password@127.0.0.1:6379```

Comment: Yeah I've tried but it didn't make any difference

Comment: I think you should watch the redis.conf file, the code looks fine, it's maybe overwrited by the .conf

Answer (score 1):

for those who are interested, the problem was related to my Redis config file. For some reason the default https://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf didn't work out for me and my docker container I used a customized version from a buddy which finally worked out. Unfortunately, I didn't know which exact setting caused the error. If it's relevant, I can link a copy to the working redis.conf file.